# Using components from appexchange within Einstein Bot

Tags: lightning-web-components, einstein-chatbot

I need to embed youtube videos in my einstein bot. Can I use either of these prebuilt items and use them to include a youtube video in my bot?

1. https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000Ecs9zUAB
2. https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000Ed00FUAR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to accomplish this by using the baseChatMessage LWC override to embed youtube videos in the bot. Once that component can handle the embed code you can configure the URL passing in the bot builder to the baseChatMessage override.

At a quick glance, the packages you refer to don't seem to have the components you need to do this in an Einstein Bot.

Comment: Thank you!  Ultimately I did it the same way as you described.